# Multi-monitor application in C++ and Opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm developing an application in C++ on Windows and i don't know in Openlg how to initialize several devices or screens for an multi-monitor application.

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create a separate render context for each window with `wglCreateContext`.